# Yellow Triangle at bootup

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot

A few days ago I bought a Samsung Galaxy S2. But, at phone start up under the Galaxy S2 Logo I see a strange Yellow Triangle. I read a few forum posts found on google, but I have some doubts about this. To be more precisely, what that means? Ah, and yes, at first start up I didn't see this triangle, he appears after I tried to update the phone software from samsungapps.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just got case of failed update. Try to have look at [this article](http://forums.overclockers.co.uk/showpost.php?p=19122037&postcount=3848) and see if you can get it sorted

Comment: I cannot get it into Download mode, when I try to start it with 3 butons clicked, it turns on as a normally startup

Comment: @hoss Try removing the battery, then while holding the buttons reinsert the battery.  Only let go of the buttons once Download Mode is shown.

Comment: I managed how to get into Download mode, I removed the battery, and it's starts, but when I try to flash it, it stops on the cache.img in Odin and don't moving forward, something like freezes, but I still can turn on the device after I force disconnect it. (Sorry, I know my english is not so good)

Comment: Ok, I have upgraded it, Kies just stays in backround, and I have to remove it, to can make an upgrade successfully.